# Escribir en un fichero de texto el resultado de un comando en Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, script

Estoy intentando escribir en un fichero de texto el resultado de un comando pero no consigo que escriba nada.
Este es mi codigo

```
f directorio2 == nil
    directorio2 = `pwd`
    directorio2 = directorio2.to_s
end

puts "#{directorio2}"
system "diff -rs #{directorio1} #{directorio2} > Compara.txt"
system "sed '/Sólo/d' Compara.txt"
```

Para este caso, quiero comparar los archivos de 2 ficheros y si no me dice un segundo fichero, este sera la ruta actual.                                                                                     El error lo da al hacer

```
directorio2 = `pwd`
```

y luego al hacer

```
system "diff -rs #{directorio1} #{directorio2} > Compara.txt"
```

hace perfectamente la primera parte, es decir, me hace el diff -rs, pero no consigo que lo escriba en el fichero de texto

Comment: Por otra parte, estás haciendo `diff ... > compara.txt`. Intenta poner una ruta absoluta, por ejemplo `/tmp/compara.txt` para tener pleno control del directorio donde se escribe el fichero.

Comment: El error es que hace perfectamente el diff pero no consigo que escriba el resultado de hacer diff en el fichero de texto que le digo.                     He probado poniendo la ruta especifica y tampoco funciona

Comment: comparar_directorios(ARGV[0],ARGV[1])                                             Los directorios los paso como parametros y en el caso de que en el segundo directorio no me ponga nada, le digo que sea la ruta actual.

Comment: Sería bueno hacer algún "print" del comando, para ver si llega correctamente el valor de los directorios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el resultado de `pwd`, el cual agrega un caracter de nueva línea `\n` al final, por lo tanto `diff` no reconoce el directorio; para arreglarlo simplemente agrega `.strip` al final:

```
if directorio2 == nil
  directorio2 = `pwd`.strip
end
```

Además, no hace falta utilizar `.to_s`, el resultado de `pwd` es un *String*.

---

No relacionado con tu pregunta, pero tu código podría modificarse un poco para acercarse más al estilo de programación de ruby:

```
directorio2 = `pwd`.strip if directorio2.nil?
```

O bien, utilizando el operador `||`:

```
directorio2 = directorio2 || `pwd`.strip
```